# write the function which substitute done object into a certain variable

Tags: javascript, protractor

I want to write the function which substitute done object (string) into a certain variable.

```
var fs = require( 'fs' );
var outFilePath = 'tmp.tsv';

describe( 'shokokaigisho', function () {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.get( 'http://meikan.yokkaichi-cci.or.jp/index.html' );

  var result_company, shozaichi, denwaBango, daihyoSha, sougyouNengetsu, houjinSetsuritsuNengetsu,
    shihonkin, juugyouinSuu, gyoshu, eigyouNaiyou, jishaPr, url, bukai;
  var content;

  it( 'open company page', function () {
    $('input[name=submit]').click();
    $('div#search_result_list:nth-of-type(2) a:nth-of-type(1)').click();

    var getTextFromTable = function ( selector, index ) {
      return element.all( by.css( selector ) ).get( index ).getText();
    };

    $('.result_company').getText().then( function ( text ) {
      result_company = text;
    });

    /*
     REDUNDANT CODE
     */
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 6 ).then( function ( text ) {
      shozaichi = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 8 ).then( function ( text ) {
      denwaBango = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 10 ).then( function ( text ) {
      daihyoSha = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 12 ).then( function ( text ) {
      sougyouNengetsu = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 14 ).then( function ( text ) {
      houjinSetsuritsuNengetsu = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 16 ).then( function ( text ) {
      shihonkin = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 18 ).then( function ( text ) {
      juugyouinSuu = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 20 ).then( function ( text ) {
      gyoshu = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 22 ).then( function ( text ) {
      eigyouNaiyou = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 24 ).then( function ( text ) {
      jishaPr = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'a', 2 ).then( function ( text ) {
      url = text;
    });
    getTextFromTable( 'p', 28 ).then( function ( text ) {
      bukai = text;
    });
  });

  it( 'save data' , function () {
    content = [
      result_company, shozaichi, denwaBango, daihyoSha, sougyouNengetsu, houjinSetsuritsuNengetsu, shihonkin,
      juugyouinSuu, gyoshu, eigyouNaiyou, jishaPr, url, bukai
    ].join('\t');

    fs.writeFileSync(outFilePath, content);
    console.log('wrote: ' + outFilePath);
  });
```

I tried to write the code as below, but this code doesn't work. Nothing is substituted into variable.

```
var getTextWaitForDone = function ( varName, tag, number ) {
  element.all( by.css( tag )).get( number ).getText().then( function ( text ) {
    varName = text;
  })
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"?

Comment: Why is your code modifying arbitrary variables anyway?

Comment: @Sprottenwels Nothing is substituted into variable.

Comment: @Bergi I am scraping web page by protractor.

Comment: So, what do you need these variables for and where would they be used?

Comment: @Bergi I've copied full code. I would like to it be helpful for you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, does it? `getTextFromTable` is asynchronous, but your `save data` task does not wait for it…

Comment: The 'it' of protractor waits for asynchronous call.